# Unsecure WiFi security in decoding encoded url in email sent by sendGrid

Tags: wifi, sendgrid, nodemailer

I sent the email by using SendGrid authenticated domain. Here I sent a URL in  tag for calling a specific URL. When I see this URL on mail it is encrypted. When I click the link it goes to the specific site well.
I think it is decoded again on the SendGrid site. But if I used Wi-Fi to connect to the internet, clicking the link can not go to the decoded URL, it is because of security.
Does anyone help me to avoid this security? I think if SendGrid sends the URL not encoded then there is no such a problem. So I hope someone helps me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem of sendgrid setting.
After logging and click tracking settings.
And make the item-"allows every link to be overwritten..." disabled.